# rails 3: (probably ajax question) need embeddable a banner on a html page that pulls a different 'joke' from our app every N seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, iframe

I've never done ajax stuff myself, and this seems like an ideal feature to add to my app to learn how to do it...

My app maintains a database of jokes.

I'd like to provide a simple way for anyone to add a small banner to the html on their webpage that will display a new joke every N seconds.

It seems the two approaches are:

1) iframe where the url/view hit by the iframe has a meta refresh tag and randomly pulls a joke each time the url is hit. But iframes can resize to fit content, and I'm not sure if browsers will refresh the contents of the iframe.

2) the right way ... ajax. But I have no idea if this is a "big" or "trivial" job for a rails 3 app, and no idea where to get started.

Any pointers on doing this would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'll use jQuery for this example but the overall technique should work pretty much the same with any other AJAX framework.

In your JavaScript, you'll want to use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to grab a new quote from your server and [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout) to get periodic updates; something like this:

```
var n_seconds = 5; // Or whatever you want.
var timer     = null;
function replace_quote() {
    // Do a $.ajax call to your server.
    $.ajax({
        url: '/some/route',
        type: 'get',
        dateType: 'htm;',
        success: function(data) {
            // Replace the quote with the new one.
            $('#quote-container').html(data);
            // And restart the timer.
            timer = setTimeout(replace_quote, 1000 * n_seconds);
        }
    });
}
replace_quote();
```

If you start out with an empty quote box then you can simply call `replace_quote()` to give it an initial value through your AJAX call.

You could also use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setInterval) to call your quote replacer. Then you wouldn't need to manually restart the timer with the `setTimeout` call but you would run the risk our updates fighting each other if an AJAX call takes longer than `n_seconds`.

If you still want to provide a link for updating the quote then bind the link to a JavaScript function something like this:

```
function manually_replace() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    replace_quote();
}
```

Calling [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) will, effectively, reset the timer when they change the quote themselves.

Then, in your Rails app, you'd add a route for `/some/route` and the controller would simply grab a random quote from your database and then use `render :partial => 'quote'` to send back just the HTML snippet for the quote without all the usual layout wrapping.

Handling AJAX requests in Rails (or any other framework) is pretty much the same as handling any other request, the only difference is that you won't send back a full page, you just send back a little piece of HTML or a blob of JSON (or XML) for the client to process and render. Hence the size difference between the client-side and server-side outlines above.

Comment: wow that's a spectacularly helpful response... I am however clueless as to "where" those different javascripts go? And what I embed on the client side html page to 'pull' data from the url mapped to some/route (say, http://myapp.com/fetch_quotes)

Comment: @jpwynn: You'd put the JavaScript in the HTML that goes into the `<iframe>`. Then you'd have a `$(function() { replace_quote() })` in there to crank up the quote stuff when the `<iframe>` DOM is ready. The client just needs a `<iframe src="/quote_iframe"></iframe>` where `/quote_iframe` would be a route for sending back the whole content with JavaScript and your `<div id="quote-container"></div>` for holding the quotes.

Comment: Thanks again! I'll try that out immediately.